# how to access files of a directory with ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

i am trying to tail all the files that are located in a directory on a remote server except the file the user enters as a third argument in the command line. For that, i need to grep the type of file to avoid confusion when directing the output of tail to another file.

The directory is `/path/to/a/file`, inside there exists two files, one called file.log and the other file.out. I would like to grep .out & .log

Here is my code:

```
files=$(ssh host find /path/to/a/file -type f -name '^file')

for type in $($files | awk -F'.' '{print $2}') ; do

ssh host find . /path/to/a/file -type f ! -name "$3" | xargs 0 tail -n 20 > /destination/dir/host.$type 2>/dev/null
```

Unfortunately, none of this works, and i don't know why.

Comment: it's fine, i fixed it!!

Comment: If you've solved it then you should probably delete this question; it isn't going to be useful for anyone else

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot wrong with your code, but the biggest thing is that you are taking arguments to `find` that should exist in the first line and passing them to `tail` in the last line. Specifically `-type f ! -name "$3"`

That will get you closer.

Build the script one step at a time. Write it as

```
ssh host find ...
```

and make sure that is outputting the right set of files. Right now it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

This regex is the problem:

```
-name '^file'
```

`-name` doesn't take regex it takes shell glob pattern.

Use this should work for you:

```
ssh host find /path/to/a/file -type f -name 'file*'
```

**Update:** To exclude a particular file from this list

```
ssh host find /path/to/a/file -type f \( -name 'file*' ! -name 'file.log00001' \)
```

Comment: i have a little question, i just realized i have one file that is called file.log00001, how do i make it ignore this fie, because i dont want to grep log00001

Comment: it gives me a syntax eroor! so i am trying to figure it out

Comment: got it!! the problem was with the paranthesis

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.